# Broken Debian 10 stable server by installing 3 or 4 small testing packages... Can't SSH anymore

Tags: debian, ssh, sudo, webserver

I wanted to install a newer version of `clone` on my Debian 10 stable server, so I started with following the tutorial in the first comment on [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing).

Then, (from memory), I ran on my server something like:

```
sudo apt-get install libaspell15/testing libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/testing...
```

...and a few more mandatory dependences for these packages.

However, immediately after the install, I couldn't use `sudo` anymore, and after logging out of my server I can't reconnect with SSH:

```
> ssh -p 2222 myuser@mydomain.com

kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 163.***.**.227 port 2222
```

So I'm complletely stuck, and I (and others) depend on thsi server working for personal and professional purpose... (I have a multi-user Nextcloud hosted on this server...)
their
Did I do something irreversible? And otherwise, how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: most providers offer a way to access a server when ssh is not working. Who is your server provider? Is rebooting the server an option?

Answer (score 4):

Debian 10 has `libc6` version 2.28-10+deb10u2, but the packages of current `testing` depend on `libc6` version 2.34 or greater. So it looks like your attempt must have triggered a libc version update, which is probably *the* most fundamental update you can do to a Linux installation.

Are you aware that your system is 2 major releases out of date? The current `stable` is Debian 12, and the current `testing` will eventually become Debian 13. You tried to install software that's *three major releases* newer than your current system state.

What you did is not irreversible, but certainly will be inconvenient to reverse. Most likely you will have to boot from external media (if a physical server) or mount the system disk of the failed server as a second disk to another VM (if a virtual machine/cloud server) to begin recovery. If you have a good backup strategy, a full restore from a pre-mistake backup might be quicker.

Once you've gained access to the system disk of the failed system, your first step should be to read `<failed system mount point>/var/log/dpkg.log` to identify each package that was updated, and the exact old versions that were installed before that: `grep upgrade <failed system mount point>/var/log/dpkg.log`.

Once you know the exact package versions that were there before the failed update, download those packages e.g. using the package search function at https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages. If you cannot find the exact version that was there before the failed update, pick the newest package version for Debian 10 "buster".

Your first goal is to get the new packages from "testing" uninstalled, then downgrading the library packages that got an unintended major release upgrade. Commands like `dpkg --force-downgrade --root=<failed system mount point> <package files that need to be downgraded>` might be the cleanest way to do it, if the recovery OS is also a Debian/Ubuntu.

---

If your recovery OS does not have `dpkg`, then you might have to extract the packages manually. The procedure for that would be:

```
cd <directory containing the *.deb files for downgrade>
ar x <something>.deb
cd <failed system mount point>
tar xvf <deb file directory>/data.tar.*z
```

Note that the manual extraction is a very brute-force method to get the essential libraries back into place so that your system will be able to run on its own, at least in single user mode. If you do this, the package management will "think" the upgraded versions are still installed, and so you will need to use the standard package management tools to downgrade the packages as soon as the tools can be used, for two reasons:

- to make the package manager's database match the files actually installed
- to make sure all the files belonging to the failed upgrade are removed, so they won't cause further conflicts.

Comment: There’s a third reason for the last part: to run the downgraded packages’ maintainer scripts. (Note also that `dpkg`’s `--root` option isn’t well supported so it too should be used with as few packages as possible to get the original system back up and sort of running, or at least allow a chroot to work using it.)